# Remove borders from image using Python OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have images with Borders like the below. Can I use OpenCV or python to remove the borders like this in images?

I used the following code to crop, but it didn't work.

```
copy = Image.fromarray(img_final_bin)
try:
    bg = Image.new(copy.mode, copy.size, copy.getpixel((0, 0)))
except:
    return None
diff = ImageChops.difference(copy, bg)
diff = ImageChops.add(diff, diff, 2.0, -100)
bbox = diff.getbbox()
if bbox:
    return np.array(copy.crop(bbox))
```

Comment: This should be solved by using contours.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using thresholding + contour filtering. The idea is to threshold to obtain a binary image. From here we find contours and filter using a maximum area threshold. We draw all contours that pass this filter onto a blank mask then perform bitwise operations to remove the border. Here's the result with the removed border

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 10000:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image,mask=mask)
result[mask==0] = (255,255,255)

cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I'm getting error as -  result[mask==0] = (255,255,255)
MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (57322428,) and data type int32

Comment: I want to retain lines inside of images. The above code you shared works , but removes or erases some lines inside of the image. @nathancy

Comment: You can try adjusting the contour area to only remove the large outer border

Answer (score -1):

You could also use Werk24's API for reading Technical Drawings: [www.werk24.io](https://werk24.io)

```py
from werk24 import W24TechreadClient, W24AskCanvasThumbnail

async with W24TechreadClient.make_from_env() as session:
    response = await session.read_drawing(document_bytes,[W24AskCanvasThumbnail()])
```

It also allows you to extract the measures etc. See:
[Fully read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny2Gi.jpg)

I work at Werk24.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.